# Fonts won't change and id height wont show

Tags: html, css

problem 1.Fonts wont change 
problem 2.Height on the "id's" wont change

problem one, is there something out of place with the font codes?

```
<head>
   <title>Jubilee Austin Developer</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
</head>
```

problem two, Ex. this is 1 of the 3 "id's" i have. its not responding to the CSS or at least its not physically showing height change

```
<section id="about">
       <div class="full-width">
         <h2>A little bit about me</h2>
         <div class="half-width">
           <p> i've made my home base in Providence, Rhode Island with my small growing family. My journey into tech started with a degree in journalism.As I started sharing my writing online, I was fascinated with how easily I could get my voice out there. I was hooked and wanted to learn how to build my own site to fit my own specific needs.</p>
         </div>
           <div class="half-width">
             <p>That curiosity then opened a door that could never be shut. When I learned how to build my first website, I realized I found something that gave me the freedom &amp; versatility I was looking for in my work. Now i've made a full switch to front-end development, where I can use my organization skills and eye for detail to write clean, elegant code.</p>
           </div>
           </div>
     </section>
```

My entire css

```
/****Base syles***/
body {
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
}
#about, #work, #contact {
    height: 600px;
}
```

Entire code in case you need it for anything

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q73h1.png

If i left anything out that you need please feel free to ask

Comment: you sure the css src is correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

About the height part: You won't see the height if the content is less high than the parent element and if there is no background or border. Add something like `border: 1px solid red;` to see the full height of your element.

```
#about, #work, #contact {
  height: 600px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply invert the order you call your styles:

```
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type='text/css'>
```